# Output Image URL in JSF XHTML containing '&'

Tags: jsf-2, xhtml

Is it possible to output an image URL in JSF XHTML containing the '&' character?

E.g.

```
<img src="http://myweb.com/servlet/generateImage?imageId=123&imageCode=eedf" />
```

Comment: This is not a JSF tag? What exactly do you want to have? But you may try to escape the ampersand `&amp;`

Comment: Next time, search on the error message you got when trying it anyway, instead of asking a rhetorical question.